# Bash + Replace string/value in column

Tags: macos, bash, replace

File: `/etc/newsyslog.conf`

I am trying to replace the 3rd column (the count column) of each line.  It appears as though the first and second columns are separated by tabs.  However, the second and third columns are separated by spaces.

I can get the value of the third column, for each line, via:

```
grep /var /etc/newsyslog.conf | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

However, I am having trouble setting/replacing the value in the third column.  The problem is that I don't know what the value of the third column will be for any given line.  That makes it difficult, using any method I know, to search/replace that specific (third column) value/string.

Thanks for any help or advice you may be able to offer.

edit: I should have mentioned that is a Mac OS 10.6 system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use awk here to avoid multiple commands:

```
awk '/\/var/{print $3}'
```

**EDIT:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} /\/var/{$3="14"}1' /etc/newsyslog.conf > temp
mv temp /etc/newsyslog.conf
```

Comment: The third column is a number.  Regardless of what it is now, I want it to be 14.

Comment: In that case, `awk '/\/var/ { $3=14 } 1'`.

Comment: Mark, that works great, but it strips out the white space between each of the columns.  Is it possible to leave that in tact and just perform replacement on the third column?

Comment: @anubhava, same reply as the one I gave to Mark.  That works great, but strips out the formatting of the spacing between the columns.  If possible, I'd like to keep the formatting/spacing between the columns and just change the third column.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, you rock.

Comment: one last question.  Would it be possible to do this in a sed one-liner without having to send the awk output to a file and perform the rename/move operation?

Comment: Sed 1 liner is possible but not straight forward since figuring out 3rd column using sed is not as simple as in awk.